# Which Array To Use?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am designing a new cinema booking system, where there will be 4 screens holding various number of seats on each.

I need to know what ARRAY or what data structure is best for ADDING and REMOVING people onto or off seats ANYWHERE they want on the screen.

I believe that I will need a 2 dimentional array structure, but any help will be much appreciated!... thank you

Comment: You answered the question, just use a 2D array. For 4 screens, you can have an ArrayList of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList is a nice simple array type list that permits adding and removing.

You could create an array of arrays if you like. That would be a 2 dimentional array.

Comment: yehs i was looking at 2d arrays. and would an ArrayList allow me to add and remove ANYWHERE within the screen? thank you

Comment: Well, I don't know how your screen works, but I know that ArrayList will allow you to insert or remove items from the start, end or middle. Normal Java arrays only allow you to replace items,, no add/remove.

Comment: if i was using a NORMAL java array then i would set the value of the node back to null so that it would be available once again isnt it?
i havent yet designed the screen, but the main data structure i need to question is which array to use to represent my screens.
there will be 4 screens. 2 holding 100 seats each and 2 holding 64 screens each. so i need to be able to choose which seats i want ANYWHERE in my 2 dimentional seat array.

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is build a class structure that will abstract out the way you are storing the data in memory.  You might do something like:

```
class Cinema {

    List<Auditorium> screens;

}

class Auditorium {
    int number;
    List<SeatRow> rows;

}

class SeatRow {
    int rowNumber
    List<Seat> seats;

}

class Seat {
    int seatNumber;
    boolean occupied;
}
```

Note:  This isn't the only solution.  You may want to look into storing `Seats` in a `Map` or some other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like 4 instances of the same data structure.  Possibly a Collection of Screen objects that contain a Collection of seats.

Answer (score 0):

I'd vote personally for a plain and simple `Seat[][]` array of the class structure suggested above. There's simply no reason to use another array as the array size probably isn't ever going to change, if it is that can be done at initialisation. Then just show them or don't on the screen by either data in a certain position or `null` for unreserved seats.

Depending on your need (do you need to remember where the guest booked?) you could even use `boolean[][]` as the bare minimum.

No matter what, just create and name four different such Seat 2D arrays. Preferably stick them in a separate class and have setters and getters.