# 2-Dimentional Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to design a cinema booking system.
it needs to have 4 screens.
2 screens holding 100 seats.
2 screens holding 64 seats.

what would be the best way at going about designing this?

what data structure should I use, and if you could explain why to use that one and also let me know the drawbacks of using that data structure it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What was wrong with [the answer you accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432839/which-array-to-use/4432901#4432901) in [this question you asked earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432839/which-array-to-use)?

Comment: I need to know why I would pick on type of data structure over say.. a linked list or doubly linked list etc, and it is also for me to learn the techniques others use and what others find more efficient. do you understand?

Comment: and it is also because noone answered all my questions in my last one!

Comment: Because you can directly index into your arrays aka your seats in a 2-D array and you can not directly index into a linked list. You would have to search through your linked list until you came to the correct node. A 2-D array is more efficient and the best suited data structure for you purpose. It better represents the data your trying to store than say a linked list.

Comment: The best structure here is clearly a binary search tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of data is so small that the most important fact is that you have to easily understand it. Arrays are fine but not flexible and if the array index is not the "seat index" this can be confusing. If the seats already have an identification system in reality it may be wise to take it over. Then you could store it in a Map - e.g. a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a the identification (e.g. a string) as key.